# Legends outside plot

Tags: plotting

I have the following code:

```
Show[
 {MapAt[Translate[#, {0, -2}] &, dataIND, 1], 
  MapAt[Translate[#, {0, 0.8}] &, datacomponent2, 1], 
  MapAt[Translate[#, {0, -0.5 - 0.9}] &, datamix1, 1], 
  MapAt[Translate[#, {0, -1.8 - 0.9}] &, datamix2, 1], 
  MapAt[Translate[#, {0, -1.1 - 0.9}] &, datamix3, 1], 
  MapAt[Translate[#, {0, -0.4}] &, datamix4, 1], 
  MapAt[Translate[#, {0, -3.5}] &, datamix5, 1]},
 PlotRange -> {{30, 82}, {-5.1, 0.8}},
 
 Epilog -> {
   
   Inset[LineLegend[{Purple}, {Style["1 K/min", 
       Bold]}, {LegendMarkerSize -> 20}, {LabelStyle -> 14}], 
    Scaled[{0.1, 0.94}]],
   
   Inset[LineLegend[{Red}, {Style["2 K/min", 
       Bold]}, {LegendMarkerSize -> 20}, {LabelStyle -> 14}], 
    Scaled[{0.1, 0.88}]],
   
   Inset[LineLegend[{Blue}, {Style["5 K/min", 
       Bold]}, {LegendMarkerSize -> 20}, {LabelStyle -> 14}], 
    Scaled[{0.1, 0.82}]],
   
   Inset[LineLegend[{Gray}, {Style["10 K/min", 
       Bold]}, {LegendMarkerSize -> 20}, {LabelStyle -> 14}], 
    Scaled[{0.105, 0.76}]],
   
   Inset[LineLegend[{Black}, {Style["20 K/min", 
       Bold]}, {LegendMarkerSize -> 20}, {LabelStyle -> 14}], 
    Scaled[{0.105, 0.7}]],
   
   Inset[LineLegend[{Orange}, {Style["30 K/min", 
       Bold]}, {LegendMarkerSize -> 20}, {LabelStyle -> 14}], 
    Scaled[{0.105, 0.64}]],
   
   
   Text[Style["SB", 16, Red], {75 + 5, 0.7}],
   
   Text[Style["88% SB", 16, Red], {75 + 5, -0.2}],
   
   Text[Style["79% SB", 16, Red], {75 + 5, -1}],
   
   Text[Style["45% SB", 16, Red], {75 + 5, -1.8}],
   
   Text[Style["30% SB", 16, Red], {75 + 5, -2.6}],
   
   Text[Style["15% SB", 16, Red], {75 + 5, -3.8}],
   
   Text[Style["IND", 16, Red], {75 + 5, -4.9}],
   
   (*scale bar*)
   Style[Line[{{44 + 5, 3 + shift}, {44 + 5, 2.5 + shift}}], Bold, 
    Thickness[0.009]], 
   Style[Line[{{44 + 5 - 0.3, 3 + shift}, {44 + 5 + 0.3, 3 + shift}}],
     Bold, Thickness[0.009]], 
   Style[Line[{{44 + 5 - 0.3, 2.5 + shift}, {44 + 5 + 0.3, 
       2.5 + shift}}], Bold, Thickness[0.009]], 
   Text[Style["0.5", 16, FontFamily -> Times, Bold, 18], {41.5 + 5, 
     2.75 + shift}]
   
   
   }
 ]
```

Which gives me the following figure:

[image]

My question is:

How can I put the legends (1 K/min, 2 K/min...etc) outside of the plotting area? For example to the right of the figure?

Answer (score 3):

Both, [PlotLegends](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) and [Callout](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html) have a flexible set of properties for various customization. I do not think you need `Inset`. Let's set up a simple example. Some data and labels:

```
words = RandomWord[7];
data = WordFrequencyData[words, "TimeSeries"];
```

`PlotLegends` do this automatically or you can also change various settings:

```
DateListLogPlot[data, PlotLegends -> words]
```

[image]

I also like the trick with `Callout`:

```
DateListLogPlot[MapThread[Callout, {Values@data, words}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The problem I am having is that because I am using `MapAt`, then `PlotLegends` does not seem to work

Comment: How can I fix this when using `MapAt`?

Comment: @John It would be helpful if your original post included a minimal example with sample data.

Answer (score 1):

```
Legended[
  ListLinePlot[Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]],
  Placed[LineLegend[{Red}, {"Text"}], {After, Center}]
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Rom38 thank you! But I get the same problem than the previous answer in which because I am using `MapAt` `PlotLegends` does not work